# CURL as a 100% usual HTTP request

Tags: php, http, curl

We have a project(website).The website however is obfuscated and we can't debug it.
It's running fine but now we need a script which will connect to it and collect some data.
However `file_get_contents` is not a solution.

The only way is with CURL.

However it's not returning anything.Status 200 with nothing as html. It seems that the CURL is recognized and denied to return actual html data.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

How can I set the CURL to pass as a simple HTTP request?!

Or the other way - how can I recognize a CURL request to my code?

Comment: You say "*it's not returning a response*" and also "*the http request is returning the data*". Well, which is it? Also, what do you mean by "*the CURL is recognized and denied*"? What headers are being returned? Are there any errors? What exactly are you trying to do, simply fetch a web-page via curl?

Comment: Its returning 200 but with not a single char. By this I think its recognizing the CURL . And yes simply get a webpage's data with CURL

Comment: Make sure your request is completely identical (headers/accepts/etc.). There's no way that they're recognizing cURL.

Comment: change up your `CURLOPT_REFERER` so it isn't coming from the same bogus link each time... use a previous or another page on the site or a google link as the referral.

Comment: You're not using headers lik Pragma, Cache-Control, and also I guess "MozillaXYZ/1.0" is not a valid browser signature. Open a network connection press F12 in Chrome, IE, or Forefox, and examine how data flows. That shall give you a hint as to what you are missing.

Comment: I've just pasted a cURL example.
I've just found it.It seems that the problem was that I'm sending the request from the same address as the server.If I try from another device it's returning the html.